# Points of Interest for France, Spain, and Italy?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, openstreetmap, data-mapping

I`m planing trip to Europe am looking for points of interest data for some regions I will be visiting.

Does anyone know of a source for POIs in KLM/KMZ/GPX or any other format with coverages for Spain, France, whole region of Alps, and Italy?

Comment: I'd go with geonames (download the data and restrict to area of interest).

Comment: What do you men by geonames? And where I can download data?

Comment: Sorry, I meant geonames.org -- they have a download page

Answer (score 2):

My way of approaching this would be to download the OpenStreetMap .pbf files directly from a source that regionally subsets the OSM data and then convert it to whatever format works best.

A great source for raw OSM data is [Geofabrik.de](https://download.geofabrik.de/europe.html). They have regionally subdivided .pbf files that can be easily converted to anything that can be read/written by gdal/ogr. I would start by reading the documentation for [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) and then follow the guidelines on the OpenStreetMap site for [.pbf to shapefile conversions](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/User:Bgirardot/How_To_Convert_osm_.pbf_files_to_Esri_Shapefiles).

Given that these regions have a high number of Points of Interest, my suggestion would be to further subset the data according to your interests (e.g. "Tourism").